# Remove Space between Drawable and Switch Button and Solve DrawableEnd Icon Problem

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-button

How to solve this problem? theres a gap between icon and switch button.

**Image 1 : Before**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:drawableStart="@drawable/baseline_dark_mode_24"
   android:drawableEnd="@drawable/baseline_light_mode_24"/>
```

[image: Theres Spaces between Drawable and Switch]

**Image 2 : After**

I already changed the value of drawablePadding to negative one.. but drawableEnd still got stacked with Switch Button.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:minWidth="0dp"
   android:minHeight="0dp"
   android:drawablePadding="-12dp"
   android:drawableStart="@drawable/baseline_dark_mode_24"
   android:drawableEnd="@drawable/baseline_light_mode_24"/>
```

[image: When i Add Drawable Padding -12 it solved, but how about with padding end drawable]

**Image 3 : with LinearLayout**

There's still gap 'ight there

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_dark_mode_24" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_light_mode_24" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

[image: Image3]